# Is there any group in which number of the normal subgroups is equal to number of the conjugacy classes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group s.t. $|G|\geq 3$.

Is there any example of $G$ such that number of the normal subgroups is equal to number of the conjugacy classes?

Comment: $G=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ has eight subgroups, which are normal since $G$ is abelian. $G$ has eight conjugacy classes since it's abelian of order 8.

Did you want a nonabelian example?

Comment: @IanColey: Thank you, Sal also found a nonabelian example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $G=S_3$, there are three normal subgroups (namely $\{e\}$, $A_3$, $S_3$) and three conjugacy classes (namely $\{e\}$, $\{(12),(13),(23)\}$, and $\{(123),(132)\}$).